# Why would my recordset be empty after running a Select?

Tags: sql, excel, excel-2007, vba

I am trying to get this code to work, but It keeps returning -1 for the RecordCount. The select statement does find values, I went to the database and ran it there. But I am unable to get any values in my program.

```
Dim quotedPubs As ADODB.Connection
    Set quotedPubs = New ADODB.Connection
    quotedPubs.Open "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB; DATA SOURCE=*****;INITIAL CATALOG=*****; User ID=****; Password=****"

    Dim hoursPubs As ADODB.Connection
    Set hoursPubs = New ADODB.Connection
    hoursPubs.Open "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB; DATA SOURCE=*****;INITIAL CATALOG=*****; User ID=****; Password=****"

    Dim lsPubs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set lsPubs = New ADODB.Recordset

    With lsPubs
        .ActiveConnection = quotedPubs

        .Open "SELECT ProjectNumber FROM hours h"

        ' WHERE h.lead = " & sEmpNum & ""
        If (lsPubs.RecordCount > 0) Then
            arr = lsPubs.GetRows(lsPubs.RecordCount)
            .Close
```

Answer (score 0):

You are openning cursor, but not moving through it, so the result of .RecordCount will allways be -1. [Check this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676701%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: But I've used that way to pull data to an array before without any problems

Comment: Are you sure? Try changing condition like this:  `If (lsPubs.RecordCount <> 0)` Then

Comment: It fails when it tries to put the values from the record set into the array because its doing GetRows(-1). Which is the same issue I had before.

Comment: I can't find the program that I wrote that did it that way, but I changed this code to use .EOF instead of the record set. It still gets -1 for recordset, but for some reason It moves past the .GetRows anyway. I now get an indexOutOfBounds when trying to loop through those values.

Comment: Add the new code to the main question, it would be easier to see, where an error could be.

Comment: I just put a watch on the array, and it is now pulling the values. I just figured out why it wont loop. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly pulled the records into the Recordset, but `lspubs.RecordCount` won't work since the Recordset's cursor is still at the first record. Try replacing

`(lsPubs.RecordCount > 0)`
with
`(not(lsPubs.EOF))`